# Coinbase API - get_address_transactions BUG

Tags: python, coinbase-api

So I am using coinbase API and the python library available by them.

```
accounts = client.get_accounts()

accountId=accounts["data"][0]["id"]    
print(client.get_address_transactions(accountId, id))
```

The above returns

```
{
  "data": []
}
```

But if I do:

```
txs = client.get_transactions(accountId)
print(txs["data"][0])
```

I get the following results:

```
{
  "address": {
    "id": id, 
    "resource": "address", 
    "resource_path": 
  }, 
  ......
  "status": "completed", 
  "type": "send"
}
```

It doesn't make sense, I have send money to myself to test this feature and the transactions don't seem to show in that api call.

The IDs are the same

Comment: Is there a question or is this just a rant? If it's an undocumented bug, head for the coinbase people

Comment: What rant? I am just having a problem. My question is how do I get the correct results.